# C++11/14/17 Lambda reference capture [&] doesn't copy [*this]

Tags: c++, lambda, copy, this, capture

Refer to this thread: https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0806r2.html

It says:

> In other words, one default capture ([&]) captures *this in the way that would be redundant when spelled out, but the other capture ([=]) captures it in the non-redundant way.

Which says that pre c++17, the [=] captures `this` as value, and [&] will capture [*this], which is ambiguous. So I had a quick test, to see if [&] captures [*this] by default.

My test code trys to see if [&] defaultly captures *this, then copy ctor should be called, and any change to its value won't affect original object, as it is a copy.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class M{
    int mI;
public:
    M() : mI(3) { cout << "ctor\n"; }
    ~M() { cout << "dtor\n"; }
    M(const M& m) {
        if (this != &m) {
            cout << "copy ctor\n";
            mI = m.mI;
        }
    }
    M& operator=(const M& m) {
        if (this != &m) {
            cout << "operator =\n";
            mI = m.mI;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    void CaptureByValue() {
        auto f1 = [=] () { // capture this
            cout << mI << '\n';
            ++(this->mI);
        };
        f1();
        cout << mI << '\n';
    }
    void CaptureByReference() {
        auto f1 = [&] () { // capture *this
            cout << mI << '\n';
            ++(this->mI);
        };
        f1();
        cout << mI << '\n';
    }
};

int main() {
    {
        M obj1;
        obj1.CaptureByValue();
    }
    cout << "------------\n";
    {
        M obj2;
        obj2.CaptureByReference();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Compile and run it with:

```
clang++ LambdaCapture.cpp -std=c++11 && ./a.out
clang++ LambdaCapture.cpp -std=c++14 && ./a.out
clang++ LambdaCapture.cpp -std=c++17 && ./a.out
```

All cases print:

```
ctor
3
4
dtor
------------
ctor
3
4
dtor
```

My questions:

(1) The result is out of my expectation: no copy ctor is called by `CaptureByReference` and the value being changed affected original `this` object. The test code didn't promoted the lambda syntax change in cpp17.

(2) I can't even change my capture into [=, *this] or [&, *this] as compiler will say:

```
LambdaCapture.cpp:25:13: error: read-only variable is not assignable
            ++(this->mI);
            ^ ~~~~~~~~~~
```

Very strange, how came out a `read-only` variable here, as to `this` pointer.

---

Appreciate your explanations.

Comment: The copy-constructor perhaps wasn't called because of [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- `[=]`, `[this]`, `[=, this]` and `[&, this]` all captures `this` by value. That is, it copies the value of the pointer that is `this`.
- `[&]` captures `*this` by reference. That is, `this` in the lambda is a pointer to `*this` outside the lambda.

The effect of the above versions with regards to `this` in the lambda will therefore be the same.

- `[=, *this]` copies all elements captured and also makes a copy of `*this` - not the `this` pointer.
- `[&, *this]` makes a reference to all elements captured but makes a copy of `*this`.

```
LambdaCapture.cpp:25:13: error: read-only variable is not assignable
            ++(this->mI);
            ^ ~~~~~~~~~~
```

That's because lambdas are `const` by default. You need to make them `mutable` in order to be able to change them.

```
auto f1 = [&, *this]() mutable { // made mutable
    cout << mI << '\n';
    ++(this->mI);                // now ok
};
```

Answer (score 3):

I think people are over-thinking this.  If you think of `this` as a pointer (which I have always done, and which of course it is), then everything naturally falls into place.  And quite honestly, I don't really know what problem the PR you cite is trying to address.  Personally, I don't think there is one.

So (apart from the deprecation warning in C++20), there is no practical difference, in terms of capturing `this`, between:

```
[=]
```

```
[&]
```

and:

```
[this]
```

In all cases, they capture the *pointer*, and that can be used inside the lambda (implicitly or explicitly) to manipulate the object in question.

Now it's true that, in principle, `[&]` captures `this` (i.e. the pointer) by reference, but since you can't assign to it that makes no practical difference and I would expect the compiler to optimise the implied dereference away.  I would also agree that capturing `this` explicitly is better style, but that's true for any variable you want to capture, IMO.  And I would strongly disagree with the notion that implicitly capturing `this` via `[&]` is in any way more legitimate than capturing it via `[=]`, but that's what they seem to have gone for.

One other minor detail is that when you capture a variable by value (by whatever method) it is, as others have pointed out, implicitly `const` in the body of the lambda.  That's to stop you making silly mistakes.  But, in the case of `this`, it's the *pointer* that's `const` (which, in effect, `this` always is anyway), not the object it's pointing to.  So you can do whatever you like to that object, just party on down.

As for capturing `*this` (which you have to do explicitly, and always have done), `[*this]` will pass a copy of the *object itself* into the lambda.  Like anything else captured by value, this will (implicitly) be `const` so declare your lambda as `mutable` if that presents a problem.

(Thank you Ted for pointing out my error).

And remember to capture responsibly, folks.  The standards committee is watching you.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking in terms of "capturing `this`" can be confusing. Think in terms of "capturing `*this`" (the current class instance).

`[&]` and `[=]` have exactly the same meaning with respect to `*this`: both capture `*this` by reference.

This makes sense for `[&]`. But this is weird for `[=]`, since it captures by value otherwise. This is why C++20 deprecates the capture of `this` by `[=]`, forcing you to manually spell either `[this]` (by reference) or `[*this]` (by value).

---

> pre c++17, the `[=]` captures `this` as value, and `[&]` will capture `[*this]`, which is ambiguous. So I had a quick test, to see if `[&]` captures `[*this]` by default.

Nope, you misunderstood the quote. Both `[=]` and `[&]` capture `*this` by reference (aka `this` by value), there is no *ambiguity*.

As I see it, the quote just points out the inconsistency of `[=]` capturing `*this` by reference.

> I can't even change my capture into `[=, *this]` or `[&, *this]` as compiler will say: `error: read-only variable is not assignable`

If you want to modify any by-value capture, the lambda needs to be `mutable`.

Comment: I disagree that it "makes sense for [&], but this is weird for [=]". In my mind `this` is a pointer and always has been. You have to dereference `this`. You can't do `this.member` in C++, so it's not a reference. So to capture it by value, a pointer to the currently working object, it makes sense. But the default of capturing `*this` when using `[&]` is the weird one here. Why would everything being captured by reference make an implicit exception for `*this`? I think the deprecation would make a lot more sense the other way around (if we have to deprecate anything in the first place).

Comment: @Tustin2121 Well, that's kind of the point of my answer, to propose a different mental model under which things *do* make sense. `this` being a pointer is kind of a language design defect, considering that it can't legally be null, and there are compilers that will optimize away `this != nullptr` checks. *"deprecation would make a lot more sense the other way around"* It wouldn't make sense if you consider how those captures are used in practice. `[&]` lambdas are often used in function arguments, for functions that will call them before returning. 1/2

Comment: 2/2 Those functions should be able to access any variable that they see; nothing can go out of scope during such usage, so it's safe. It makes no sense to restrict access to `this` from those lambdas (you can't possibly capture it by reference, since it's a prvalue), it's just going to make things verbose for no good reason. On the other hand, I don't think I've ever seen a `[=]` lambda in the wild, but I imagine that if one used that, one would expect the resulting lambda to be self-sufficient, so one wouldn't want to have any pointers in it, `this` or otherwise.

Comment: "I don't think I've ever seen a [=] lambda in the wild" - I mean, I did show you one in my question, from which you linked to here. That example is an (IP-scrubbed, MWE) real-world example using Qt, where a button widget is created on the heap, connected to whatever it needs to do upon click, and then the reference is let go (memory is managed via Qt's tree structure of widgets, so one doesn't have to keep around reference pointers to individual objects). In fact, I don't think I've *ever* used `[&]` before because nearly every lambda I've used outlives its creation scope.

Comment: @Tustin2121 *"did show you one in my question"* Fair enough. :P *"nearly every lambda I've used outlives its creation scope"* When I make those, I tend to not rely on default `=` capture, because it looks too brittle to me. (If I swap out a reference for a pointer, the capture suddenly changes meaning, and so on.)