# C++: Are pointers captured by & lambdas a reference to the object, or a reference to the pointer to the object?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++20

I was recently told that C++20 is deprecating the default capture of `this` when using `[=]`. This seems to make absolutely no sense to me as to how this was confusing in the first place. Did I just not understand how captures worked in the first place?

So, take this example:

```cpp
void BehaviorClass::refreshDisplay()
{
   // ...remove all widgets from m_container...
   for (auto x : listOfData)
   {
      auto w = new QPushButtonSubclass(x); // displays the data
      QObject::connect(w, &QAbstractButton::click, [=](){ onButtonClick(w); }); // this lambda
      m_container->layout()->addWidget(w);
   }
   m_container->update();
}

void BehaviorClass::onButtonClick(QPushButtonSubclass* w)
{
   // ...do something with w...
}
```

The marked lambda is apparently perfectly fine in C++17, but gives warnings in c++20. I understand that the preferred replacement is `[=, this](){ onButtonClick(w); }`, but it just seems messy to start adding variables to the capture list when I've never had to before. So I figured I'd just change this to `[&](){ onButtonClick(w); }`, since apparently it's perfectly fine to implicitly capture `this` by reference. But this now just made me more confused.

If I have `[=](){ onButtonClick(w); }`, it copies `this` for the implicit dereference for `this->onButtonClick` and it copies the pointer `w` to pass as the argument. That makes sense to me.

But if I have `[&](){ onButtonClick(w); }`, it captures `this` for the implicit deference for `this->onButtonClick` and it... does what with `w`? The documentation says it captures only local variables by reference, presumably meaning that it has references to those local variables, seeing as it also talks about object lifetimes and making sure references to these variables stay active for the lifetime of the lambda. But the local variable in question is a pointer to an object on the heap. So what does it capture here?

### My question:

Does `[&]` capture a reference to the *local variable* `w`, or does it capture the *pointer* the local variable is pointing at??

Because the *former* would imply that as soon as the for loop goes to the next iteration, the captured `w` variable is going to be pointing at something different and all the buttons will call `onButtonClick` with the last button that was created (or worse, something else entirely because by the time the button is clicked, the stack will have unwound and gone down other code paths).

But the *latter* would imply a normal copy of the pointer value, and thus using `[&]` would seem like the right thing to do all the time. But then what's with all the talk about lifetimes??

And if `this`, which is just a pointer to an object, has always been copied by reference, to the point that they're ***getting rid of*** the implicit copying of it using `[=]`, meaning you have to explicitly tell it to capture by reference `this`...?????

I don't even know anymore.... Help me understand this, please??

Comment: 1. There's no special logic for capturing pointers. You get a reference to a pointer, not to what it points to. 2. Regarding the deprecation thing, see e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73199073/2752075).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was recently told that C++20 is deprecating the default capture of this when using `[=]`. This seems to make absolutely no sense to me as to how this was confusing in the first place.

The argument is that with `[=]` it is unclear as to whether it is `this` or `*this` that is copied. One point bolstering the confusion is that `[=]` captured `this` by copy but `[&]` captured `*this` by reference -- which is to say, they both do the same thing despite being different syntax.

> Does `[&]` capture a reference to the local variable `w`, or does it capture the pointer the local variable is pointing at??

`[&]` captures by reference, full stop. So this would capture the local variable `w` by reference. Which would be a bad choice, since that would pretty likely dangle (I am not familiar with how Qt works but  I think it's a pretty safe bet that this would not work).

The correct way to translate

```cpp
QObject::connect(w, &QAbstractButton::click, [=](){ onButtonClick(w); });
```

into non-deprecated C++20 would be to write the lambda capture as either `[=, this]` or `[w, this]`. I personally prefer the former (for that matter, I personally preferred just `[=]` but so it goes).

Comment: Okay, so the "confusion" they reference with the `[=]` capture then is that people didn't remember that `this` is a pointer, and always has been? Because this deprecation thing now makes even less sense to me, if they're getting rid of the `[=]` meaning `[=, this]` but *keeping* `[&]` meaning `[&, *this]`. It should be the other way around, in my mind. Thanks for this explaination.

Comment: @Tustin2121 Well, `[&]` capturing `*this` by reference is obvious, because no other meaning makes sense. But I'm not sure it's that much of a stretch to see that `[=]` could have instead captured `*this` by value.

Comment: Well, okay, follow up question then: When you do `[&]` and thus capture `*this`, do you use `this->call()` or `this.call()` inside the lambda? Because I would expect the latter now, if you're capturing `*this` into a reference instead of `this`. Pointers you have to dereference explicitly, whereas references can just use a dot operator as if they were local fields / variables. If you still use `this->` inside the lambda, that would imply the pointer inside `this` was copied by value, thus 'inconstancy with `[&]`'. -- Idk, this never confused me before, so maybe I just can't see it.

Comment: "that people didn't remember that this is a pointer" -- usually you don't write this in the lambda, you write "x" or some other identifier, and people have to make the leap to that is a member variable, and then the leap from there that [=] will capture it effectively by reference. Or if "x" wasn't a member variable, writing "x" will capture it by copy. It's a lot of hidden information.